# How to display tag-slug as a class of tr in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I use the following code to take the tags from entries to class of  tags. 
How edit this code, to display tags slug, not the full name (I always have only one tag in this posts). I need to have f.E. not First Tag but first-tag.

```
 <?php

      // The Query
      query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'best-offer', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

      // The Loop
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
     <tr class="<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
foreach($posttags as $tag) {
echo $tag->name . ''; 
}
}
?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$tag->slug`, instead of using `$tag->name`, as per http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags#Member_Variables